# <div> background doesn't change, but only in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I've labelled a `<div>` with a class and I've changed the `background-color` to create a solid banner at the top of the page. This has worked in Firefox and IE, but not in Chrome. I also found that if I apply the style inline (as opposed to an external style sheet), then Chrome does acknowledge it.

I'd rather not use an inline style because of the pain it causes with maintenance. I probed further and found that Chrome isn't liking applying color to other backgrounds too.

I'm thrown by this. As I say: it works in other browsers so I'm wondering if the CSS hierarchy differs between platforms. Does anyone know what's going on? I'd be grateful for a solution, but even more so if you could explain.

I'm trying to apply CSS to `.banner`

Here's the HTML:

```
{% load cms_tags staticfiles sekizai_tags menu_tags %}
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv"X-UA-Compatible" Content = "IE=Edge">
        <meta name = "viewport" content="width=device-width", initial-scale=1>

        <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico">

        <title>{% block title %}MyBlog Title{% endblock title %}</title>
        <link href="{% static 'myblog.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudfare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel = "stylesheet">

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

        <!-- MyBlog custom styles -->
        <link href="{% static 'myblog.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src=https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->

        {% render_block "css" %}
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <!--<div class="blog-header"></div>-->
            <div class ="banner">
                <h1 id="test">My blog</h1>
                <!--<img class = "blog-header" src="../../media/images/banner.png">-->
            </div>
            {% cms_toolbar %}
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                        <!--<a href=""><img src="{% static '#' %}"/></a>-->
                    </div>
                    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            {% show_menu 0 1 0 100 "menu.html" %}
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>

            <div class="container-full">
                {% block content %}{% endblock content %}
            </div>

            <div class="push"></div>
        </div>  
        <footer class="footer">
         <div class="container-full">
          <p class="text-muted">{% block footer %}My blog&copy; 2015{%endblock footer%}</p>
         </div>
        </footer>

        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bu -->
        <script src="{% static "ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js" %}"></script>

        {% render_block "js" %}
    </body>
</html>
```

And the CSS:

```
html {
    position : relative;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%
}
body {
    /* Margin bottom by footer height */
    /*margin-bottom: 60px;*/
    font-family : Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    color: #555;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-height:100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0
}
.wrapper {
    min-height:100%;
    margin-bottom:-60px;
}
h1, .h1, h2, .h2, h3, .h3, h4, .h4, h5, .h5, h6, .h6 {
    margin-top: 0;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serfi;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #333;
}
.footer,.push {
    height:50px;
}
.footer {
    position: absolute;
    clear:both
    padding-bottom:0
    padding-left : 0px;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 60px;
    height:100%;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
footer.footer {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
 }
.blog-header {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    border-style: solid;
    /*border-bottom: solid #C6C6C6*/
}
.container-full {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0
}
.blog-title {
    margin-top: 30px;
    width: 500px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: normal;
}
.blog-description{
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #999;
}
.sidebar-module{
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 0 -15px 15px;
}
.sidebar-module-inset {
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
.sidebar-module-inset p:last-child,
.sidebar-module-inset ul:last-child,
.sidebar-module-inset ol:last-child{
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.pager {
    margin-bottom: 60px;
    text-align: left
}
.pager > li > a {
    width: 140px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 30px;
}
.blog-post{
    margin-bottom: 60px;
}
.blog-post-title{
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    font-size: 40px;
}
.blog-post-meta {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    color : #999;
}
body > container {
    padding: 0px 0px 0
}
.container .text-muted {
    margin: 0 0;
}
.footer > .container {
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 0;
    bottom:0
}
.row {
    margin-right: 0px!important;
}
.navbar { margin-bottom: 0 }
.footer { margin-bottom: 0 }
.banner {background-color: green;
        min-height: 120px
}
```

Comment: Can you share the rendered HTML with a [mcve]?

Comment: Your best option is to do some investigation using the chrome developer tools. Right click the element that's not displaying how you want and choose `inspect`, then in the console window look for the part where the styles are displayed and click the `computed` tab and scroll down to background. Here you will be able to see exactly what style is currently applied and, if you click the arrow to expand it, you will be able to see where the style is coming from, helping you to identify potential style conflicts.

Comment: Do you mean screenshot?

Comment: Thanks delinear, I'll give that a go. Soolie, I need you to elaborate a bit. It's minimal because I'm interested in the hierarchy, complete with both HTML and CSS, and verifiable. If you let me know what you would like changing, then I can look at doing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try force-refreshing chrome using ctrl + f5, this should refresh the CSS properly.

Comment: You are a legend!

Comment: Glad to have helped!

Answer (score 0):

Your provided code works in Chrome.
See https://jsfiddle.net/73xgouey/

However, I see that you have left-out semicolon in your CSS at several places, which could impact rendering in specific version of Chrome.

```
.footer {
    position: absolute;
    clear:both /* this */
    padding-bottom:0 /* and this */
    padding-left : 0px;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 60px;
    height:100%;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

This is found throughout your code, yet it should be avoided.

Comment: Thanks! I'll go through and see if that helps. Should I always place the semi-colon on the last element in a list too? I can figure out if that's personal preference. Have you tried it in actual Chrome or just jsfiddle? On my version, it's playing up

Comment: Adding semi-colons hasn't fixed the banner, unfortunately

Comment: Just a heads up - you don't need to terminate a style rule with a semi-colon (`;`) if it is the last rule declared in the style block.

Comment: You could not add the semicolon to the last line of a class only. If you not add semicolon on a line in the middle of a class the other line isn't apply.

Comment: Thanks, it was only the two in `.footer` that I missed out then